# Links in WordPress working only when I am logged as admin

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hyperlink, admin

After migrating website from localhost I have one problem. The links are not working. When I click on any link it is still redirecting to homepage. But when I am logged as **admin** its working fine. I've never encountered this problem before.
I am wondering if it can be some problem with DB or with `.httaccess` but not sure. I also changed both links in `WP_options` table in DB to the right one.
Debugging on `localhost` was working perfectly (also like guest and admin)
Its really weird that its not happening when I am logged as admin.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do your links look like? What are the URLs in them? Please provide code necessary for resolving your issue.

Comment: Hello links looks like this for my woocomerce categroy - http://example.com/shop/categoryproduct/
also its not working for normal pages like for example  example.com/contact
ist only work if i am logged as admin

Comment: We really need some code to know what could possibly be wrong. `example.com/contact` tells us nothing. Preferably a fiddle of a working example.

Comment: just let me know which code you need and i will provide. the page i smartbag.sk